# unserialize: need to debug to screen, human-readable

Tags: php, deserialization

I'm working with MyBB, a mod called NewPoints Shop.

This is the serialized field:

```
$barnInfo['newpoints_items'] = "a:7:{i:0;s:1:"2";i:1;s:1:"2";i:2;s:1:"2";i:3;s:1:"2";i:4;s:1:"5";i:5;s:1:"7";i:6;s:1:"7";}" 

// the deserialized field represents this data:
4 Lumber (Item ID 2)
1 Mushroom (Item ID 5)
2 Carrot (Item ID 7)
(And perhaps 0 of every other item - there are 9 items: Item ID 1, 2, 3, ...7, 8, 9)
```

In their code, they call

```
$items = unserialize($barnInfo['newpoints_items']);
```

I'm having a really hard time manipulating this data. I figure if I can print the deserialized data to the screen, I can figure out how to work with it. But I can't figure out how to print anything meaningfull. I've played with print_r with no success.

```
// displays '1' , quite unhelpful!
print_r(unserialize($barnInfo['newpoints_items'] ))
// I tried and got very confusing results that don't seem to correspond at all http://blog.tanist.co.uk/files/unserialize/index.php
```

**Question:** How can I print the deserialized data to the screen so that I can figure out what is what?

**Answer: ** MyBB is a little tricky with printing things to the screen, but this works: `"<pre>" . htmlspecialchars(print_r($items, true)) . "</pre> ... "`

Comment: What PHP variable holds the serialized data - `$barnInfo`?

Comment: @Jason I'm reading from a database , so `$barnInfo['newpoints_items']` contains the serialized information.

Comment: try `var_dump(unserialize($barnInfo['newpoint_items']))`

Comment: http://codepad.org/9ySCTXtX - don't know where you got '1' from

Comment: @Austin Brunkhorst, it's `1`. You'd be better off debugging `var_dump($barnInfo['newpoints_items'])` as I suspect it doesn't contain serialized data.

Comment: I found the problem is that it actually isn't printing any arrays at all - the problem is with myBB rendering my page, so I will ask them elswehere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$barnInfo['newpoint_items']` actually contains serialized data, then wrapping your `print_r` in `pre` tags would make it more readable.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(unserialize($barnInfo['newpoint_items']));
echo '</pre>';
```